# How to print content of selected item in ListView into a textbox when selected?

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to display content of the selected row into text box. This code doesn't work because it only add first selected item.

EDIT: This kind of work but my display look like this: `ListViewSubItem: {a} ListViewSubItem: {b}`

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PC.SubItems[1].Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PC.SubItems[2].Text))
{
      txtPc.Text = e.Item.SubItems[1].ToString() 
      + " " + e.Item.SubItems[2].ToString();
}
```

EDIT: This works well:

```
private void SelectedItem(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (tabSelectPage.SelectedTab != tabPage2)
        txtSelected.Text = "User: " + e.Item.SubItems[1].Text + 
            "Pass" + e.Item.SubItems[2].Text;
    else
        txtSelected.Text = "URL: " + e.Item.SubItems[1].Text + 
            "User: " + e.Item.SubItems[2].Text + 
            "Pass" + e.Item.SubItems[3].Text;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "print into a desktop"???

Comment: @Sai Kalyan Akshinthala: Oops! I meant text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have done it:

```
    private void SelectedItem(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabSelectPage.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
            txtSelected.Text = " User Name:  " + e.Item.SubItems[1].Text +
                "     Password:  " + e.Item.SubItems[2].Text;
        else if (tabSelectPage.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
            txtSelected.Text = " URL:  " + e.Item.SubItems[1].Text +
                "     User Name:  " + e.Item.SubItems[2].Text +
                "     Password:  " + e.Item.SubItems[3].Text;
        else if (tabSelectPage.SelectedTab == tabPage3)
            txtSelected.Text = " Software Name:  " + e.Item.SubItems[1].Text +
                "     Serial Code:  " + e.Item.SubItems[2].Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs.ItemIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitemselectionchangedeventargs.itemindex.aspx) property.

Comment: It doesn't give me content of the selection.